# Java: How to communicate between an annotation processor and another project?

Tags: java, annotations, preprocessor, java-6

I have an own **annotation processor** *(let's call it MyProcessor)* and a project *(let's call it MyProject)* which uses the processor by
passing `-processor` to `javac`.

**Now I need MyProcessor to produce some output and make it available for MyProject.**

I have following options (and problems):

- Let MyProcessor write a file to the path, specified by the property `user.dir`.
  **Problem:** from the point of view of MyProcessor, `user.dir` is always my home dir, not the path of MyProject.
- Pass the current directory of MyProject to MyProcessor using `javac`'s `-A` option.
  **Problem:** It's an ugly hard-coded path: `/some/path/to/MyProject/`.
- Let MyProcessor generate some source files, which then would be compiled by `javac` together with MyProject, so that MyProject can refer to this compiled class and retrieve data from it.
  **Problem:** It's too complex for such an easy (?) task.
- *What other options are there?*

Can someone please suggest, how to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Processor.init()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html#init(javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment)) method (which you've implemented) is invoked with [ProcessingEnvironment](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/ProcessingEnvironment.html) as parameter which, in turn, has a `getFiler()` method returning a [Filer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Filer.html) instance.

You should be using the `createResource()` method of the `Filer` (assuming the output being generated is neither class nor source; otherwise use appropriate `create` method for that) and write your output to either [class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/StandardLocation.html#CLASS_OUTPUT) or [source](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/StandardLocation.html#SOURCE_OUTPUT) locations (former is probably preferable, but it depends on what you're doing). Both are overridable via command-line switches if need be, but are well-defined as they are to be used in a build process.

Comment: Thanks! You've saved my day ;) I create a FileObject using Filer and write some properties using `myProperties.store(fileObject.openOutputStream,"");`